# Primefaces datatable scrollable width auto

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Primefaces datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="vmTbl" value="#{plnVacationMatrix.vacationList}" var="v" scrollable="true" 
  frozenColumns="2" scrollWidth="1000" scrollHeight="600">

    <p:column headerText="Employee" style="min-width:330px">
        <h:outputText value="#{v.employee.surnameNameCode}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Company" style="min-width:200px">
        <h:outputText value="#{v.company.shortName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="1" style="min-width:20px">
        <h:outputText value="#{v.week1}" />
    </p:column>

    (...)

</p:datatable>
```

In the table there are 55 columns in total and they don't fit the viewport.
I'd like to have this table width the same as viewport, but primefaces requires to specify **scrollWidth** and **scrollHeight** of the table when using **scrollable**.

I've tried to use jQuery to fix the table with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var totalWidth = $(window).width();
        var totalHeight = $(window).height();
        $(".ui-datatable-frozenlayout-right .ui-datatable-scrollable-header").width(totalWidth - 500);
        $(".ui-datatable-frozenlayout-right .ui-datatable-scrollable-body").width(totalWidth - 500);
        $(".ui-datatable-scrollable-body").height(totalHeight - 100);
    });
</script>
```

... but the above changes table during data loading, and after table is fullfilled it takes again values from **scrollWidth** parameter :-(

Do you have any idea how to solve that?